# How to create a feature Horizontally from button

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

Right now when I click the "Add a product button", the product form appears below the previous product. Is there a way to get it to appear horizontally, not vertically? I defined my addNewProduct function in Typescript, but I call it in HTML. Where would I change how it appears?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex boxes are great for this situations. Use the style `display: flex` on a div that is parent of all the product1, product2 boxes.

If you have added more boxes so it gets wider than your screen / the parent div, it will just continue. If you want it to break to a new line if it is to wide, use the css `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parents css.

You can also use the css `align-items: center` on the parent class to align all the product boxes center horizontally if they don't have the same height.

html file:

```
    <button class="button" (click)="addProduct()">Add product</button>
    <div class="parent">
      <div *ngFor="let product of products, let i = index" class="child">
         <h5>Product {{i+1}}</h5>
         <p>Sales price</p>
         <input [(ngModel)]="product.price" \>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css file:

```
.parent {
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap; // use this to make it break to a new line, if all the childs are wider than the parent;
   align-items: center; // use this to align the product boxes center horizontally if they are not of same height
}

.child {
   margin: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black; // same border color as your example
}

.buttonContainer {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.button {
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked in making the boxes go horizontal. However, my button also moved down to the same line as the boxes. How do I keep the button one line on top of the boxes?

Comment: move the button outside of the div with the parent class (the one that has display:flex). I updated the code to match.

Comment: Thank you! That works. Sorry for so many questions but how do I edit the css to make the boxes appear with some spaces? Right now they appear connected to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The boxes are block elements, hence why the appear vertically. You have to set the CSS property of the boxes to "display: inline-block".

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. My boxes are a component class, I'm not sure if that changes anything. I used Angular and inside the Component, I defined a templateUrl which contains the html file that is regenerated with each button click.